# SQL Session ID generation by two columns

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, presto

I'm generating session IDs by SQL for a table that contains users, group, and event time. A session is defined as a window of 10 minutes. My current implementation generates session ids; however, there is one caveat there can be users who belong to more than one group and that doesn't get reflected in the session id categorization

### Example Schema:

```
userid |  group  | event_time
001        A      2020-06-20 02:04:50.000
001        A.     2020-06-20 02:06:12.000
001.       A      2020-06-20 02:17:16.000
001.       B.     2020-06-20 02:20:10.000
001.       A.     2020-06-20 02:28:13.000
002.       A.     2020-06-20 04:13:97.000
```

SQL snippet:

```
tmp_table AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY
                userid
            ORDER BY
                event_time
        ) AS user_row,
        LAG(userid) OVER (
            PARTITION BY
                userid
            ORDER BY
                event_time
        ) AS prev_user,
        LAG(event_time) OVER (
            PARTITION BY userid
            ORDER BY
                event_time
        ) AS prev_action
    FROM table
    ORDER BY
        userid,
        event_time
)

SELECT
    *,
    CASE
        WHEN prev_user = user_row AND DATE_DIFF('minute', prev_action, event_time) < 10
            THEN LAG(user_row) OVER (
            PARTITION BY
                userid
            ORDER BY
                user_row
        )
        ELSE user_row
    END AS session_id
FROM tmp_table
```

However, this generates

```
userid |  group  | event_time             | session_id
001        A      2020-06-20 02:04:50.000.  1
001        A.     2020-06-20 02:06:12.000.  1
001.       A      2020-06-20 02:17:16.000.  2
001.       B.     2020-06-20 02:20:10.000.  2
001.       A.     2020-06-20 02:28:13.000.  2
002.       A.     2020-06-20 04:13:97.000.  1
```

When it should be

```
userid |  group  | event_time             | session_id
001        A      2020-06-20 02:04:50.000.  1
001        A.     2020-06-20 02:06:12.000.  1
001.       A      2020-06-20 02:17:16.000.  2
001.       B.     2020-06-20 02:20:10.000.  1
001.       A.     2020-06-20 02:28:13.000.  3
002.       A.     2020-06-20 04:13:97.000.  1
```

Since userid 001 belongs to both A and B and what happens in A and B are independent from each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the calculation for the session.  Simply look at the previous event time for each `userid`/`group` combination.  Then a new session starts when the difference is greater than or equal to 10:

```
WITH tmp_table AS (
      SELECT t.*,
             LAG(event_time) OVER (PARTITION BY userid, group ORDER BY event_time) as prev_event_time      
      FROM table t
    )
SELECT t.*,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_DIFF('minute', prev_event_time, event_time) < 10
                THEN 0 ELSE 1
           END) OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY event_time)
FROM tmp_table t;
```

I'm not sure how your code is supposed to be working.  But I would expect `group` in the `partition by` if you want to restart counting for each group.

Comment: I tried putting group in the partition by but for some reason all the session ids jus tbecame sequentual regardless of the 10 minute limit. Maybe I need to put another lag statement?

Comment: Nevermind, I missed a statement, it works now. Thank you!